# Style an avatar image in a button like Facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am styling a project that requires to have an avatar and a dropdown menu showing account settings in my nav. I've made the drop-down already, however, I can't style the avatar in the button. The button keeps spanning too much space so it ruin my nav bar. Is there any solution pls? Thanks really much for helping me[this is when i use ordinary text, however it becomes a mess when i change it to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQsAN.png)

When i change it to an  tag:

```js
const account = document.querySelector(".account__wrapper button");
const accountOption = document.querySelector(".account__wrapper .account__option");
const buttonStatus = accountOption.style;
function btnClicked() {
    if (buttonStatus.display == "none") {
        accountOption.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        accountOption.style.display = "none";
    }
}

account.addEventListener("click", btnClicked);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}

li, ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.account__option a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
}

.nav-element__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__area {
    background-color: rgba(62, 70, 116, .8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 9vh;
}

.right-section { 
    margin-left: auto;
}

.account__wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 110%;
}

.account__option {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
    transform: translateX(13%);
}

#account-part {
    margin-right: 2vw;
}

#account-part button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 9vh;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 120%;
}

#account-part img {
    width: 4%;
}

.account__option a {
    padding: .7rem 1.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/887cee56b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Techno Guild</title>
</head>
<body>  
<header class="header-area">
    <nav class="nav__area">
        <div class="left-section nav-element__wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">FSC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-section nav-element__wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">To-do list</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li id="account-part" class="account__wrapper">
                    <button>
                        <img src="https://vnn-imgs-a1.vgcloud.vn/image1.ictnews.vn/_Files/2020/03/17/trend-avatar-1.jpg" alt=""><span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="account__option" style="display: none;">
                        <a href="#">Account</a>
                        <a href="#">Log out</a>
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<script src="/js/navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the image a height of 1em and width auto it will stay within the navbar alongside the characters.

```js
const account = document.querySelector(".account__wrapper button");
const accountOption = document.querySelector(".account__wrapper .account__option");
const buttonStatus = accountOption.style;
function btnClicked() {
    if (buttonStatus.display == "none") {
        accountOption.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        accountOption.style.display = "none";
    }
}

account.addEventListener("click", btnClicked);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}

li, ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

.account__option a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
}

.nav-element__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__area {
    background-color: rgba(62, 70, 116, .8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 9vh;
}

.right-section { 
    margin-left: auto;
}

.account__wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 110%;
}

.account__option {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
    transform: translateX(13%);
}

#account-part {
    margin-right: 2vw;
}

#account-part button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 9vh;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:1.1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 120%;
}

#account-part img {
    width: 4%;
}

.account__option a {
    padding: .7rem 1.5rem;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 191, 191);
}
#account-part button img {
  width: auto;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/887cee56b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Techno Guild</title>
</head>
<body>  
<header class="header-area">
    <nav class="nav__area">
        <div class="left-section nav-element__wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">FSC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-section nav-element__wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">To-do list</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li id="account-part" class="account__wrapper">
                    <button>
                        <img src="https://vnn-imgs-a1.vgcloud.vn/image1.ictnews.vn/_Files/2020/03/17/trend-avatar-1.jpg" alt=""><span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="account__option" style="display: none;">
                        <a href="#">Account</a>
                        <a href="#">Log out</a>
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<script src="/js/navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. But could you tell me how does it work? I would be appreciate as you explain it for me. But anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, glad it worked. All it's doing is as I said in the answer, it sets the image height to 1em which corresponds to the height of your characters in the rest of the navbar. It sets the width to auto which means it will keep its correct aspect ratio. Then next to it is still your span with the down arrow icon in it which just fits in like any ordinary character would. Hope that helps. Let me know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Okay now I got it. It's an outstanding solution that I have never think about it. Thanks a lot mate.